# About continuity of a function in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^d, s\in \{-1,+1\}^d$ and we define $f(y)$ as follows:

$$f(y)=\|y\|^2 + g(s)$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean distance, $s$ is such that $s_i=sign(y_i)$, $g(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x\in \{-1,1\}^d$ and $sign$ function is defined in the standard way.

> Is it true that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^d$ except in a set of Lebesgue measure zero?

$\|y\|^2$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^d$ but $g(s)$ makes $f$ piecewise continuous in the orthants of $\mathbb{R}^d$ that correspond to $s\in \{-1,1\}^d$ i.e. there is a bijection between $\{-1,1\}^d$ and orthants of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ is continuous in each orthant of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and I think $f$ is not continuous in a set of Lebesgue measure zero although I could not prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $s_i = sign(y_i)$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, corrected that.

Comment: The complement of the union of  the orthants has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, thanks.

Comment: @Garfield I'm guessing you meant to specify that $g$ is an arbitrary **_continuous_** function!